# Is it possible to eliminate the console flicker when opening the PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell

I really hate the black console flicker that occurs when opening the PowerShell ISE. Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: Just curious, do you mean the console window that pops up for .00045 of a second when ISE loads, or something else?

Comment: @Matt: I'm pretty sure that's what they meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hack, but it works:

1. Right click Desktop
2. New Shortcut... Enter the path to Powershell ISE: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
3. Name the shortcut Right click on the new shortcut
4. Click Properties
5. Click the Run Dropdown, select Minimized.
6. Click OK.
7. Run Powershell ISE from the icon, should be no more console window pop up, but the ISE will still start maximized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a diffrent and more advanced PowerShell IDE that dosent have a cmd console flicer if it bothers you that much. I would sugest using [powerGUI](http://www.powergui.org) it is just as free as the ISE but give you IntelliSense during editing.